# LocalDateTime set ZoneId globally

Tags: java, spring

How can I set the `ZoneId.of("GMT+2")` for all further instances of `LocalDateTime` in a spring app?

currently i'm using this: `LocalDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("GMT+2"))`

thanks

Comment: doesn't (setting)  the default `TimeZone` work for you?

Comment: `LocalDateTime` has no concept of time zone. You are using the wrong class. Use `ZonedDateTime` instead. Pass the desired/expected time zone rather than relying on the JVM’s current default zone.  `ZonedDateTime.now( ZoneId.of( "Europe/Bucharest" ) )`